# Would it be grammatically correct if I use "having" in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, have

Would it be grammatically correct if I use **"having"** in the sentence below? I am not sure about using it as it gives a sense of **"to possess"**. Is it correct to use **'have'** in the continuous tense in this case?

**Reference Link**: See this [website](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/non-continuous-verbs)

**Sentence**:
The phrases "compiled language" and "interpreted language" are nonsensical and are used without **having** an appropriate notion.

Comment: I think you need to get the facts right first. The terms 'compiled language' and 'interpreted language' may be misnomers, but they're accepted terms and used by experts in the field. // Were your facts right, the sentence would still have problems. ' ... by those not having a full understanding.'

Comment: [A First Course in
Scientific Computing
Symbolic, Graphic, and Numeric
Modeling Using Maple, Java,
Mathematica, and Fortran90 Princeton University Press: Wangberg, Augustson et al {p4}](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/Books/IntroBook/Samples/Sample.pdf): 'In Part 1 of this book we will use a high-level interpreted language, either
Maple or Mathematica. In Part 2 we will use a high-level compiled language,
either Java or Fortran90'.

Comment: C is a programming language whose source code is intended to be compiled to produce an executable file consisting of machine code. Perl is a programming language whose source code is intended to be processed by an interpreting program, called an 'interpreter'. It is economical of words and time to call these 'compiled' and 'interpreted' languages respectively. Sensible people see nothing wrong in this.

Comment: ...without having an appropriate notion; who is having it?

Comment: @Michael Harvey: The evanescent state of my boisterousness and the footslogging desire to vegetate are bludgeoning me to tarry my belaboring to the next day. I will reply to your arguments tomorrow.

Comment: Strong smell of troll around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence may easily have a context in which the sentiments are true. I therefore set aside any discussion (which in any case belongs elsewhere) of programming.

We are then left with a simplified version: *A and B are nonsensical and are used without having an appropriate notion.* Not only does *having* give the feeling of possession but the subject of *having* is not clear. A and B, being inanimate,  cannot have notions, so presumably the subject is those who use the phrases A and B. (Forgive me if *subject* is not quite the right grammatical term for a noun before a gerund. I, being a physicist, simply regard *I* as the subject of *being*).

Among the many possibilities, I therefore suggest *... and are sometimes used without an appropriate notion*, *... and are used without appropriate notions*, or *... and users' notions of them may be inappropriate*. My own taste is for the last one.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: How kind of you :) I am smiling.

Comment: @Anton If you are saying that the sentence is ungrammatical or otherwise wrong when *having* is used, then I disagree. The subject is simply elided from the sentence: *The phrases "compiled language" and "interpreted language" are nonsensical and are used [by people] without [those people] having an appropriate notion [of their use].* I don't find that elision to be anything unusual, and it's how I immediately interpreted the sentence. Although the sentence is somewhat clumsy, it's still understandable as written. It would also be more likely if previous sentences had mentioned the subjects.

Comment: @Jason I do not say it is wrong. I understood it as you have interpolated. Nevertheless, Niraj objects to its giving a possessive feel and I am uneasy because there is no clear subject. No doubt, as you say, the context would have provided a clearer notion of the subject.